# Is it possible to find $g(\kappa)$ in this equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, power-series, integral-equations, mellin-transform

I have ran into the following integral equation as part of my research.

For $\xi = (\alpha\theta)^{1/\alpha}$ and for all $\theta>0$.

I have the following equality
$$\int\limits_0^\infty g(\kappa) \exp{\left[-\frac{\left(\xi +
\kappa \right)^2}{2\alpha\theta}\right]} d\kappa %
= \exp{\left[-\frac{\left(\xi - x_0\right)^2}{2\alpha\theta}\right]}%.
$$
This condition can also be presented as follows
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty
g(\kappa)\exp{\left(-\kappa^2/(2\alpha \theta) -\xi\kappa/(\alpha\theta)\right)} 
d\kappa = \exp{\left(-\frac{x_0^2 - 2\xi
x_0}{2\alpha\theta}\right)}$$
I assume $\kappa$  to depend on $\theta$, Is there a way to find $g(\kappa)$ here ? Can it be interpreted as some form of convolution ?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so. You can take $g(k)$ to be basically any function then compute the integral and rescale $g$ such that the result matches. For example the (constant) function $$g(k) = \frac{2 e^{-\frac{\zeta -x_0}{2 \alpha  \theta }}}{\sqrt{2\pi \alpha \theta } \cdot \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\zeta }{\sqrt{2\alpha  \theta  }}\right)}$$ works. If you restrict $g$ to be, say, a smooth function that only depend on $k$ and $x_0$ then it might be possible to find a unique solution (but I don't know).

Comment: @Winther, thank you, i will think about that.

Comment: @Winther, I wanted to get your opinion about something, assuming g was a function of $\kappa$ and $x_0$. Can
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation#Power_series_solution_for_integral_equations
be applied to find $g$.